# How to make VS code support unity statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have a solid problem, my **VS code doesn't even know what means** `using UnityEngine;` so it's not more easier with it. I tried everything, **installing random Unity Plugins, searching for .jar file to import**, but *nothing*, **this is the last place** where I can ask. Even my old programing group doesn't helped.

**What I want** is, when I am typing `Vec` to instantly see above `Vector2` and things like this.

Big ***THANKS*** to everyone who responds positively.

Comment: There seems to be a ton in the doc about Unity in vs code : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity. There must be support. It must be a simple step. Btw why not community edition, last time i checked it was in the unity installer

Comment: Make sure you've set "External Script Editor" to Visual Studio Code in Edit > Preferences > External Tools and then press regenerate project files. This has always fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure tere are no errors in your code first, it needs to compile (no red un-clerable stuff in the console)

Main thing: make sure you have all the .net components that vscode needs, read through its output, it ususally tells you that you need to have .net 4.7.1 or so, so install precisely that version (I never remember if you need runtime or sdk but I have a feeling you need both). Installing a newer one should work but I try to have that exact version installed as well, output window in vscode will tell you what is missing.

Next thing to try is go into package manager and downgrade you vscode support package to a lower version (1.1.3 was recommended by someone, I tried 1.2 and it works for me too, the newest one often doesn't)

After you did all that, close vscode, and use Assets/open c# project

Comment: Thanks, I tried and checked **all**, but nothing, thanks for your responding

Comment: I've had this issue with each OS, reinstall, and each time I managed to get it to work somehow. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Just use Visual Studio. I never had any issues with it.